# Instrument only show old version of my app

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, profile

I´m looking for memory leaks usign the Instrument (profile). When I run my app on the device, the last vesion of the app is not showed, the Instruments show an old version of my app. If I use the simulator every thing is fine.

Any idea about that problem?

Best regards

Comment: Just delete your app and install it using xcode

Comment: I did it but the old version is still appearing

Comment: clean the project and then run it

Comment: Hi Tendulkar, I had two apps with the same ID. I removed all version and every thing is ok now

Comment: ok good have a good day

Comment: Did you removed all versions from the device ?